# AppCenter IOS App store connection error finding app

Tags: xamarin, appcenter

I am trying to connect appcenter to app store, I can create the account connection to app center however it wont find the app that is already published:

No apps found on App Store Connect
Please create an app and refresh

Any idea?

Comment: I had same issue, you won’t get answer here, contact app center support and report the bug. I have done that.

Comment: Yup, same issue here

Comment: AppCenter issues can be [found here](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues), although there is nothing related to this particular problem.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug in the AppCenter code. The browser console shows an error for the request to get apps. e.g. the POST request to:

```
https://appcenter.ms/api/v0.1/apple/itunes/get_all_apps
```

returns HTTP 500 with the response

```
{
    "code": "internal_server_error",
    "message": "{\"code\":\"internal_server_error\",\"message\":\"undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass\"}"
}
```

Unfortunately this looks it will need Microsoft to fix it.

---

**Update**

The AppCenter team have come back with a message to say it's an issue with FastLane, [specifically this issue](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20444) which then points the finger back to Apple.

There is a status page for this issue which can be [found here](https://status.appcenter.ms/incidents/ts3n2ks33wt9).

Answer (score 0):

Appcenter support said it is a problem with fastlane and they will try get it sorted as soon as possible